# AWS Step function: Relationship between OutputPath and Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I've read the AWS documentation (multiple times), but it's as clear as mud to me.  Can anyone explain what the relationship is between the **OutputPath**, **Parameters** and **Payload** values in this state definition?  The Lambda in question generates a random number and some fake user details, so nothing is actually passed into it - it's the very first step in the state machine.

The Lambda function returns a piece of JSON and the details are stored in the **body** property of that JSON.  The next state (Limit greater than 10?) is able to read those details using **$.body.username**, so I cannot understand where **Payload** comes from, or how/if that gets passed to the next state.  My shoddy understanding is that the **OutputPath** determines which part of the response are passed to the next state, but I am accessing the **body** property and not a **Payload** property successfully in the next state, which suggest my understanding is way off.

```
"Generate dummy limit":
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
  "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
  "Parameters": {
    "Payload.$": "$",
    "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:my-function"
  },
  "Next": "Limit greater than 10?"
}
```

So:

- What does "Payload.$":"$" do?
- What does "OutputPath": "$.Payload" do?
- Where the flip does "Payload" come from?  Is it a built-in value?

I've got a working step function, but I don't know how it's working :(

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-jsonpath-effectively-in-aws-step-functions/) link is **much** more helpful:

When Lambda functions are executed via Step Functions the execution returns the Lambda response inside the **Payload** property of the Task response (so it's a built in property that is generated by a step functions Task).

So "OutputPath": "$.Payload" means the contents of the **Payload** property from the Task response will be passed to the next state.

"Payload.$": "$" - This instructs that task to take all the input (as denoted by "$") and assign it to a new input property called **Payload**.  The trailing $ symbol after **Payload** is required to let Step Functions know that we are reading this value from a JSON path (as opposed to just manually providing a value).

In my case, i'm not passing any values in, so the **Payload** property will be empty when my Lambda is invoked.